# How to calculate gas and storage for an operation?

Tags: fees, gas, storage

In protocol 003_PsddFKi3, how can the gas and storage usage be calculated without doing a dry-run in a node?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no other way, you have to simulate what the operation does if you want to estimate this value, and this is exactly what a dry run does. You could try to reimplement it outside of a node, but the approach would be the same.

Comment: That's true. If doing it outside of the node the same logic must be used as in the dry run. For operations that doesn't involve parameters or script, I guess a simplified logic could be used in the client, in order to reduce the traffic to the node.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation available [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alphanet/introduction/howtouse.html#validation) you can get the gas and storage cost of the operation you plan to broadcast to the network by passing the parameter `--dry-run` to the client node

Quoting the doc it mentions

> Another important use of validation is to determine gas and storage
>   limits. The node first simulates the execution of a Michelson program
>   and takes trace of the amount of gas and storage. Then the client
>   sends the transaction with the right limits for gas and storage based
>   on that indicated by the node. This is why we were able to submit
>   transactions without specifying this limits, they were computed for
>   us.

So officially there's indeed no alternative way short of implementing your own validator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Taquito in node project using `npm install --save @taquito/taquito`,
2. Install Taquito signer package using `npm install --save @taquito/signer`
3. Copy below code in javascript file say `index.js`,
4. Run `$ node index.js`

**Code:**

```
const TezosToolkit = require('@taquito/taquito').TezosToolkit;
const tezos = new TezosToolkit("Place Tezos node RPC URL here");
const InMemorySigner = require('@taquito/signer').InMemorySigner;
tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner("Place the private key of sender here") });
const input = {
    "destination"       :   "Place destination address here",
    "amount"            :   "Place amount to be sent",
    "source"            :   "Place sender address here",
    "senderPrivateKey"  :   "Place sender private key here"
}
const estimate = async function(input){
    const estimated = await tezos.estimate
                .transfer({ to: input.destination, amount: input.amount })
                .then((est) => {
                    const estimated = {
                        "gasLimit"     :   est.gasLimit.toString(),
                        "storageLimit" :   est.storageLimit.toString(),
                        "suggestedFee" :   est.suggestedFeeMutez.toString()
                    }
                    return estimated;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("ERROR: Estimation failed!!",error);
                });
    return estimated;
}
console.log(await estimate);
```

Gas limit, Storage limit and fee will print in the command-line interface.
Thank you.